# Return the text string of el.content in pandoc filter

Tags: filter, lua, pandoc

When using pandoc filter, I just want to get the text of `el.content`, but it return a Table!

The `.md` as follows(just for debug):

```markdown
[It's so easy!]{color="red"}. Today is Monday.
```

I want to get the string `It's so easy!` be printed. So, I write the code:

```lua
function Span(el)
  color  = el.attributes['color']
  strTxt = el.content
  print(strTxt)
end
```

but **it's not true**! By using `el.text` also the same!

Comment: according to the documentation `el.content` is supposed to be a "List of Inlines" which is a Lua table. So I'm not sure why you expect it to be a string

Comment: I want to split the text string.Any method to get the content with a easy way? Thanks! And I dont care `el.content` can do what, just want to some method to return all the tex between the square brakets.

Comment: I don't know Pandoc. What's in that table? I'd presume that you can access a text like `el.content[1].text` or something similar. just print all the table contents or refer to the manual

Comment: It only return the first text, not the whole content.

Comment: so inside that Lua table there is only a fraction of your text? do you think you could manage to provide more information on the actual output? "it's not true" isn't helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module `pandoc.utils` contains a function [`stringify`](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#pandoc.utils.stringify) which will convert an element into a list:

```lua
function Span(el)
  -- Print just the text in the span; removes all markup.
  print(pandoc.utils.stringify(el))
end
```

This will print `It’s so easy!` (note the effect of pandoc's smart handling of apostrophes: a closing curly quote has replaced the straight apostrophe `'`).

It's also possible to print the output in specific markup language (requires pandoc 2.17 or later):

```lua
function Span(el)
  -- Prints the span's contents as Markdown
  print(pandoc.write(pandoc.Pandoc{pandoc.Plain(el)}, 'markdown'))
end
```

Consult the [Lua filters docs](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) for more info on how to use them.

Comment: Cool! Many thanks! It can return the `el`'s `content` as string. But `'` still show as a strange word in output.

Comment: [stringify](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#pandoc.utils.stringify) also removes all formatting,such as **bold**, which means it will change the element's **real `content`**.

Comment: I believe the "strange word output" is due to an encoding problem. Pandoc uses UTF-8, maybe your terminal expects something different? Windows works with UTF-16 most of the time. Your second comment seems to imply that you didn't expect markup to be lost. Can you describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: For the Second (let us give a very simple example): if markdown like this: `[It's so **easy**!]{color="red"}. Today is Monday.`, I want to get `It's so **easy**!` where the output do not remove the double `*`.

Comment: Short version: not possible. Long version: you can do that, but it's not easy. However, I'd be curious to hear the bigger story, I'm worried that we are looking at a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Amazing! It's look like `so easy`, but in fact it's **`so difficult`**! (I am not skilled at lua-filter, maybe I should give up the further try.)

Answer (score 1):

So I have never used Pandoc before so applogize if I'm making anything wrong here.

I installed Pandoc, I created a filter.lua like yours

```
function Span(el)
  print(el.content)
end
```

I created a test.md with your contents

```
[It's so easy!]{color="red"}. Today is Monday.
```

And I ran pandoc --lua-filter=filter.lua -f markdown test.md

and it printed

```
table: 00000000078ba480
<p><span color="red">ItÔÇÖs so easy!</span>. Today is Monday.</p>
```

Whatever happened to that `'`...

So I took a look inside that table

```
function Span(el)
  for k,v in pairs(el.content) do print(k,v) end
end
```

Which printed

```
1       table: 0000000007874e90
2       table: 0000000007875010
3       table: 0000000007875050
4       table: 0000000007875090
5       table: 0000000007876190
<p><span color="red">ItÔÇÖs so easy!</span>. Today is Monday.</p>
```

So that must be the list of Inlines that the manual mentions

Let's look inside!

```
function Span(el)
  for i, tbl in ipairs(el.content) do
    print(string.format("Table #%d contains: ", i))
    for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
      print(k,v)
    end
  end
end
```

which prints

```
Table #1 contains:
text    Itâ?Ts
Table #2 contains:
Table #3 contains:
text    so
Table #4 contains:
Table #5 contains:
text    easy!
<p><span color="red">ItÔÇÖs so easy!</span>. Today is Monday.</p>
```

So those tables in that table are most likely some Inline objects and they have a text attribute that bears the words you were looking for.

You see it is pretty simple to examine mysterious tables using a few loops and prints.

Comment: All you work are so quickly, many thanks! 1) `el.content` doses return `Tables`. 2) `'` is strange. 3) Still we did not get the whole string `It's so easy!`.

Comment: @user26992 `el.content` does not return anything. its's a reference to a table, not a function.  combining those words to a single string is trivial. though I don't know pandoc so I don't know why the whitespace is turned to empty tables.

Comment: Great, it's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following lua-filter will colourise the texts that are marked-up in md style as `[It's so **easy**!]{color="red"}`, as well as plain texts.
The idea to specify a font colour by name and by hex-RGB (e.g. `[It's so **easy**!]{color="#5588FF"}`) is originally implemented [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown-cookbook/issues/194#issuecomment-1111027768), and is not mine. I just modified the original lua-filter so that we can also apply the filter to create [revealjs](https://revealjs.com/) or [beamer](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) slides.

```lua
Span = function(span)
  color = span.attributes['color']
  -- if no color attribute, return unchange
  if color == nil then return span end

  -- tranform to <span style="color: red;"></span>
  if FORMAT:match 'html' or FORMAT:match 'revealjs' then
    -- remove color attributes
    span.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- use style attribute instead
    span.attributes['style'] = 'color: ' .. color .. ';'
    -- return full span element
    return span
  elseif FORMAT:match 'latex' or FORMAT:match 'beamer' then
    -- remove color attributes
    span.attributes['color'] = nil
    -- encapsulate in latex code
    if string.sub(color, 1, 1) == "#" and #color == 7 then
      -- TODO: requires xcolor
      local R = tostring(tonumber(string.sub(color, 2, 3), 16))
      local G = tostring(tonumber(string.sub(color, 4, 5), 16))
      local B = tostring(tonumber(string.sub(color, 6, 7), 16))
      table.insert(
        span.content, 1,
        pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\textcolor[RGB]{'..R..','..G..','..B..'}{')
      )
    elseif string.sub(color, 1, 1) == "#" and #color == 4 then
      -- TODO: requires xcolor
      local R = tostring(tonumber(string.sub(color, 2, 2), 16) * 0x11)
      local G = tostring(tonumber(string.sub(color, 3, 3), 16) * 0x11)
      local B = tostring(tonumber(string.sub(color, 4, 4), 16) * 0x11)
      table.insert(
        span.content, 1,
        pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\textcolor[RGB]{'..R..','..G..','..B..'}{')
      )
    else
      table.insert(
        span.content, 1,
        pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\textcolor{'..color..'}{')
      )
    end
    table.insert(
      span.content,
      pandoc.RawInline('latex', '}')
    )
    -- returns only span content
    return span.content
  else
    -- for other format return unchanged
    return span
  end
end
```